# MSChart : Labels repeating in X-axis in bar chart

Tags: c#, mschart

I'm trying following code to create bar chart where bars must be grouped by user name but somehow getting question label repeated shown below,

[image]

My Data Table is something like,

```
Question="Gravimetry"
Project-test1=0
Project-test2=1

Question="Sub-Surface"
Project-test1=0
Project-test2=2

Question="VSP"
Project-test1=2
Project-test2=3
.....
```

C# is,

```
            Series Series = new Series("Series1");
            Chart4.Series.Add("Series1");
            Chart4.Series.Add("Series2");

            Chart4.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea1");

            // Set series chart type
            Chart4.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
            Chart4.Series["Series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;


            // Set series point width
            Chart4.Series["Series1"]["PointWidth"] = "0.6";
            Chart4.Series["Series2"]["PointWidth"] = "0.6";

            // Show data points labels
            Chart4.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            Chart4.Series["Series2"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

            // Set data points label style
            Chart4.Series["Series1"]["BarLabelStyle"] = "Center";
            Chart4.Series["Series2"]["BarLabelStyle"] = "Center";

            // Draw as 3D Cylinder
            Chart4.Series["Series1"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
            Chart4.Series["Series2"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";

            Chart4.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;

            Chart4.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;

            Chart4.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Question";

            //Chart4.Series["Series1"].YValuesPerPoint = 2;

            Chart4.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Project-test1";
            Chart4.Series["Series2"].YValueMembers = "Project-test2";

            Chart4.DataBind();
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Chart.DataBindTable method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd467865.aspx); it appears to bind to tables and provide grouping by column. For example:

```
Chart4.DataBindTable(dt, "Question");
```

Should create a series for each of the additional columns in the table, grouping by the Question column.

If you need more customization, there is also the [Chart.DataBindCrossTable method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489089.aspx), which allows you to specify which columns are used to create the series values.